# Prevent default cursor placement

Tags: javascript, events, input, focus, caret

Here's the code I use to set caret position before third symbol of input value. It works fine, with one exception — the function setCaretPosition() executes a moment after the default script fires while I want it happen immediately. Is there any chance to avoid default cursor placement without adding an overlay element?

```
function setCaretPosition(elemId, caretPos) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elemId);

    el.value = el.value;
    // ^ this is used to not only get "focus", but
    // to make sure we don't have it everything -selected-
    // (it causes an issue in chrome, and having it doesn't hurt any other browser)

    if (el !== null) {

        if (el.createTextRange) {
            var range = el.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
            return true;
        }

        else {
            // (el.selectionStart === 0 added for Firefox bug)
            if (el.selectionStart || el.selectionStart === 0) {
                el.focus();
                el.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
                return true;
            }

            else  { // fail city, fortunately this never happens (as far as I've tested) :)
                el.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

var inputId = 'test';

document.getElementById(inputId).addEventListener('click', function() {
    setCaretPosition(inputId, 2);
},false)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/82fnpmf6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way to avoid this abrupt change of position. We can change the perception by doing some trickery. You can clone the input and make it overlap over the original as soon as you click on the input field.  Use a timeout to change the order of fields again so that the non blinking clone goes behind the original again. So basically the user sees a non selected input for a few milliseconds which should be enough time to position your cursor where it belongs.

Since the change of position happens within less than a second I dont think it will be bother the user.